# Passing record id from quick action to lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, action

I have an action on Contact page which opens a lightning component.
How do I pass the current Contact record id to the lightning component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html)

basically, you have implement the force:hasRecordId attribute:

```
<aura:component controller="yourControllerifany"
implements="force:hasRecordId">
```

declare it in your component:

`<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />`

and in your client side controller, you should be able to fetch the record ID:

```
"recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
```

further documentation on using actions and recordid's can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action_recordid.htm)

Comment: No need to declare an aura:attribute separately, if `force:hasRecordId` is implemented `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />` is inherited automatically

Comment: I see, Good to know! i just noticed it is mentioned in the second documentation link I referred, however, the salesforce doc includes Both, the aura attribute and the force:recordId in the code snippet examples.

Answer (score 1):

The best Possible workaround:

Component:

```
    <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
        var state = pageRef.state; // state holds any query params
        var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef;
        /*
            *For some reason, the string starts with "1.", if somebody knows why,
            *this solution could be better generalized.
        */
         if (base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) {
            base64Context = base64Context.substring(2);
        }
        var addressableContext = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Context));
        component.set("v.recordId", addressableContext.attributes.recordId);
})
```

It is because of the context is changing when you overridden the standard button.